# Changing react state based on number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react and am trying to change my component based upon the state. Having the state as a number works perfectly, but I'm not sure why I'm not able to incease or decrease their values

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        userPrize: 1
    })
}

nextPrize() {
    this.setState(userPrize: this.state.userPrize + 1);
}

previousPrize() {
    this.setState(userPrize: this.state.userPrize - 1);
}


render() {
        switch(this.state.userPrize) {
            case 1:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize() } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize() } />
            case 2:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize() } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize() } />
            case 3:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize() } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize() } />
            case 4:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize() } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize() } />
            case 5:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize() } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize() } />
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown prize state");
        }
  }
```

I'm not sure if you can change a state using the state in the function the way that I have? I have tried a few different ways but keep getting syntax errors, e.g. unexpected token inside the next and previousPrize functions. As I'm still getting used to react, I'm also wondering if this is the best practice way to pass down the state to change component as well?

Comment: You're forgetting, but it's not necessary, the prevState `nextPrize() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ userPrize : prevState.userPrize + 1 }))
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `{}` in your `setState` call:

`setState` accepts an object:

```
nextPrize() {
    this.setState({ userPrize: this.state.userPrize + 1 });
}

previousPrize() {
    this.setState({ userPrize: this.state.userPrize - 1 });
}
```

EDIT:

You also have a few issues in your code. You aren't binding the function you are passing in as props, instead you are immediately calling them which will cause problems. Also, you can combine `nextPrize` and `previousPrize` into a single function. I've updated it here:

```
setPrize = (amt) => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({ userPrize: prevState.userPrize + amt }) );
}

render() {
    switch(this.state.userPrize) {
        case 1:
            return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, 1) } previousPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, -1) } />
        case 2:
            return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, 1) } previousPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, -1) } />
        case 3:
            return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, 1) } previousPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, -1) } />
        case 4:
            return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, 1) } previousPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, -1) } />
        case 5:
            return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, 1) } previousPrize={ this.setPrize.bind(this, -1) } />
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown prize state");
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for second argument in bind call

Comment: @MaheshBhuva How else would you pass in the `amt` param to the `setPrize` function?

Comment: Oh. Sorry I didn't notice the edited `setPrize`. But you can use arrow function if you want to get rid of bind call.
`nextPrize = {() => this.setPrize(1)}`
similar for `previousSize`

Comment: @MaheshBhuva You don't want to pass anonymous function to children as props because on each render, a new function will be created meaning that react will see a change to the component and trigger a re-render. This can be expensive and cause performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

All of other the (so far) answers are discouraged when updating the state based on a previous state value. The "correct" way of doing this is:

```
nextPrize() {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({userPrize: prevState.userPrize + 1}));
}

previousPrize() {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({userPrize: prevState.userPrize - 1}));
}
```

To quote the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> The first argument is an updater function with the signature:
>
> ```
> (prevState, props) => stateChange
> ```
>
> `prevState` is a reference to the previous state. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from `prevState` and `props`. For instance, suppose we wanted to increment a value in state by `props.step`:
>
> ```
> this.setState((prevState, props) => {  
>   return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step};
> });
> ```

---

That being said, there is no reason for you to use a switch case here, since you are returning the same thing for values 1-5 anyway. Also, by doing `this.nextPrize()` you are invocing that function meaning that you will update the state on render and you will enter an endless loop. Just pass the reference to that function:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.userPrize > 5) return null;
  return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. Hadn't taken a look at these docs in a while (and hadn't had any problems with it) but good to get a refresher.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        userPrize: 1
    })
}

nextPrize = () => {
    this.setState({userPrize: this.state.userPrize + 1});
}

previousPrize = () => {
    this.setState({userPrize: this.state.userPrize - 1});
}


render() {
        switch(this.state.userPrize) {
            case 1:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
            case 2:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
            case 3:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
            case 4:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize} previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
            case 5:
                return <Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
            default:
                throw new Error("Unknown prize state");
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set state takes an object:

```
this.setState({
  userPrize: this.state.userPrize + 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your functions without the parantheses :

```
<Prizes userPrize={this.state.userPrize} nextPrize={ this.nextPrize } previousPrize={ this.previousPrize } />
```

Also the **this** keyword have to be binded to your function, write your functions this way (and it will automatically available) :

```
nextPrize = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({userPrize: prevState.userPrize - 1}));
}
```

also look at the **setState** and **prevState** syntax.